# How to check file/device access permission in Linux and Windows in python using opencv?

Tags: python, linux, windows, opencv

I want to know how to check and catch file/device access permission/privileged issues using openCV in Linux and windows .

Comment: OpenCV is for image processing. It does not make a lot of sense to me to use it to check permissions and privileges. There are platform specific APIs to do it.

Comment: as @jww stated, you're better off not using OpenCV to directly check permissions and privileges. Maybe you're looking for the python library 'os'. Here is a link to the documentation - https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html